# How to keep some cells always visible while data entry?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an excel spread sheet that keeps some data. I have to add rows to it multiple times everyday. While inserting new rows, I mistype some values time to time, and it's really hard to find these cells later. To keep these mistakes as low as possible, I have a few cells (in columns after my actual data ends) having formulas (some `SUMIF`s) that verify my last few lines. The problem is that these problem-indicator cells will scroll up and become invisible as I insert new rows and I have to cut-paste them to the bottom of the sheet after adding a few rows.

[image]

So, is it possible to kind of fix these cells somewhere on the screen?

Keep in mind that I don't want them in another sheet, since I need their values in real time as I insert/edit my real data.

BTW, I'm using M.S Excel pro 2016.

Comment: Share some sample data along with expected output,, and be specific where SUMIF has been used!

Comment: @RajeshS Done...

Comment: @saasth have you tried View, Frazze Pane command?

Comment: Thanks @RajeshS, that does the trick. Post an answer that I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This can be solved by using Freeze Panes command.*

- Select an appropriate Column/Row.
- Go to View TAB.

[image]

- Click on Freeze Panes.

**N.B.** Similar effect can be generated by **Split** the Screen also.